# Why is this variable not considered to be 0 despite debugger saying otherwise?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jsx, equals-operator

I'm writing a React component that takes a total number of reviews as a prop. When the number of reviews is 0, I want to render an element stating

```
<div>No reviews yet.</div>
```

Otherwise, I render elements containing review data. Here is the component and its context:

```
const Stats = ({good, neutral, bad, totalReviews}) => {
    if ({totalReviews} === 0) 
        return <div>No reviews yet.</div>
    else {
        return (
            <div>
                <Stat text="Total: " amount={totalReviews} />
            </div>
        );
    }
}

const App = () => {
  const [good, setGood] = useState(0);
  const [neutral, setNeutral] = useState(0);
  const [bad, setBad] = useState(0);

  let totalReviews = good + neutral + bad;

  return (
    <div>  
        <Stats totalReviews={totalReviews} />
    </div>
  )
}
```

I have used the `debugger` command to check in Chrome's developer console the values of each variable. It shows that `totalReviews = 0`. The variables `good, neutral, and bad` all also `= 0`.

I've also used `console.log(totalReviews)`.
0 is displayed by the `console.log`. How come my program enters the second conditional as if totalReviews isn't 0?

Comment: Remove the {} from around totalReviews

Comment: You are comparing an object `{totalReviews}` with a number `0`. Remove the `{}` from `{totalReviews}`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`if (totalReviews === 0)`

You only wrap js statements in curly braces inside jsx, but your if statement is just regular js.

Comment: Indeed. The reason why the condition did not behave as intended is because of the semantics of the `===` operator. 
From this page: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Comparison_Operators#Identity "The identity operator [===] returns true if the operands are strictly equal with no type conversion."
The key part of this sentence is **no type conversion**.

Comment: Thank you. I initially thought I needed the curly braces since I wanted to check props.totalReview (which would be {totalReviews} after deconstructing in the component declaration). It would seem I only need {} for jsx statements since totalReviews is now a JS variable (props.totalReviews being a JS statement).

Answer (score 1):

Problem with your if condition.
 it should be `if (totalReviews === 0)` or `if (totalReviews == 0)` to avoid strongly type conversation check.
You have added `{}` inside if condtion which is not a stadard way